# Add friend model to belongs to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Table friend:

```
$table->integer('user_id');
```

Table friend_user:

```
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->integer('friend_id');
$table->primary(['user_id', 'friend_id']);
```

User model:

```
public function friends()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'friend_user', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
}
```

UserController:

```
public function getAddFriend(User $user)
{
    Auth::user()->friends()->attach($user->id);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Why is it that if I write `$user->id` in `attach()`, the data is not inserted into table `friend_user`, but if I write the id(1, 2 or something else) in `attach()`, the data is inserted into the table `friend_user`?

How to add the data in the table `friend_user` after clicking?

Comment: Are you sure `$user->id` contains the data you think it does?

Comment: try to dd($user) if you model binding is setup incorrectly it returns an empty model

Comment: When wrote number of id(1, 2 or something else) in attach, data insert into table friend_user, therefore I wrote $user->id.

Comment: Yes, but i do not think your model binding is working, try to dd($user); and see what it prints? and how do you define your route?

Comment: Just a sidenote, you've got a rather complicated relationship here. If `User A` adds `User B` as a friend, `$userA->friends` would contain `User B`, but `$userB->friends` would not contain `User A`. You'd have to attach twice `Auth::user()->friends()->attach($user->id)` and `$user->friends()->attach(Auth::user()->id);` (which is technically duplication of data), or modify the relationship to be bi-directional (which is also quite complicated)

Comment: My route for add friends: 
Route::get('/addfriend', 'UserController@getAddFriend')->name('add.friend');

Answer (score 1):

I believe the underlying problem is model binding, i presume your route has a parameter called user. Then i would explicit define your model binding in `AppServiceProvider.php` or `RouteServiceProvider.php` `boot()` method.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::model('user', User::class);
```

Comment: I tried to wrote this and recieved error: General error: 1364 Field 'first_name' doesn't have a default value
```
public function getAddFriend(User $user)
    {
      Auth::user()->friends()->attach($user->id);
      Auth::user()->friends()->save($user);

      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: Updated my answer with a suggestion, but post your route and i will adjust it

Comment: You don't use `save()` on `many-to-many`, as both records should already exist in the database before you associate them with `attach()`. I would actually say you should never use `save()` on a `many-to-many`, unless you have a model for the pivot table (which is also not recommended, but necessary in some outlying cases)

Comment: You are right sir, was to quick on that one, just so common to use that one when creating new models :)

Comment: I had this error: `Class 'App\Providers\Route' not found` after added  `Route::model('user', User::class);` in boot() in  AppServiceProvider.php.

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Comment: I don’t have an error now, but the data is not sent to the friend_user table.

Comment: try to dd() around your code and see if user has the correct friends etc.

Comment: After I written it `Auth::user()->friends()->attach(dd($user->id));` and click on button I see null. I'm not received id for user.

Comment: The only thing i can think off is you are sending the wrong id to the url